# Two UISearchBars showing up in a view controller when only one is instantiated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have two search bars shhowing up in a view controller. It's strange because I have the same exact code in another vc and it works fine. (the search bar in the background shouldn't be there)

here's a screenshot:

[image]

I added the delegates: `<UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>`

then in the .h:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

in the .m:

```
@synthesize searchBar;
```

in the viewDidLoad:

```
 self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(204, 11, 107,44);
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;

    //customize the searchbar
    UITextField *searchField = [self.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    [searchField setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_panel.png"]];
        
    [self.searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    UIImage *searchimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"searchfield_bg.png"];
    
    for (UIView *subview in self.searchBar.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
            UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:subview.frame];
            bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:searchimg];
            [self.searchBar insertSubview:bg aboveSubview:subview];
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        }
    }
    
    [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
```

and that's it. I have nothing to do with the searchBar in the Storyboard view controller xib it's added programmatically in the viewDidLoad method

thanks for any help

Comment: If you don't have any search bar in the storyboard, then why do you have an IBOutlet to a search bar? Also, you are not creating a search bar in the above code, just modifying one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an outlet, your `UISearchBar` very likely also exists in the storyboard or the xib. Since you're also creating it in the `viewDidLoad`, you're making a second copy of it. Take another look at your storyboard.

Comment: thanks. there is no outlet in the .h just the property and there's nothing in the storyboard. If I right click on the view controller in  the storyboard there's no mention of the searchBar

Comment: If you don't use it as an IBOutlet, you should remove the IBOutlet qualifier on the property, for clarity and to avoid connecting it by accident.

Comment: Agree with @Brendon. Also removing the IBOutlet can help because if you do have a search bar in your storyboard that you've forgotten about, you'll now get a run-time error, alerting you of the problem.